# How to force a record to save itself even if I have not changed any attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In order to clean up some bad data I added a before save callback. Now I need to force all the models to be saved again. However no update operation happens if I do this

```
User.first.save
```

How do I force all the models to perform save operation even though I don't have any attributes changed.

Comment: Actually, in Rails 3.3.17, calling `save` now *does* call `before_save` callbacks, even if nothing has been modified.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should be able to use [`touch`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Timestamp/touch), it fires callbacks when it saves.

Alternatively turn off partial_updates: `ActiveRecord::Base.partial_updates = false`

Comment: touch doesn't seem to execute callbacks anymore, at least in rails 3.03 the docs say: "Saves the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current time. Please note that no validation is performed and no callbacks are executed. If an attribute name is passed, that attribute is updated along with updated_at/on attributes."

Comment: At least in Rails 4.2 it executes `after_touch`, `after_commit` and `after_rollback` callbacks: "Saves the record with the updated_at/on attributes set to the current time. Please note that no validation is performed and only the after_touch, after_commit and after_rollback callbacks are executed."

Answer (score 18):

As Josh Rickard commented to the accepted answer, since Rails 3.0.X `touch` does not invoke validation and callbacks anymore.

You can, however, "touch" it manually with `model.update_attribute(:updated_at,Time.now)` and skip validation and invoke callbacks that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use **touch** to solve your problem, as **cwninja's** answer points out.

True, it doesn't trigger traditional callbacks anymore in latest Rails, as mentioned by **Josh Rickard**. But it does trigger the **after_touch** callback.

See bottom of this page:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Comment: Confirming __touch__ still works. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the attributes aren't modified it won't save. If you modified something during the cleanup, it should be able to be saved.

Comment: cleanup happens during the callback. And the callbacks are not fired until I change the attributes which I am not doing.